# KivyMD - why is the MDList just on half of the screen

Tags: kivy, kivy-language, kivymd

I want to use an ButtonNavigation + MDList, but the list is just to see on half of the screen (see screenshot). Have can I display the list on the whole screen?

```
<CreateScreen>
    name: "create_screen"
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: "vertical"
        ScrollView:
            MDList:
                TwoLineAvatarIconListItem:
                    id: list1
                    text: "Date"
                    secondary_text: "Time"
                    IconLeftWidget:
                        icon: "github"
                        on_release: print("Hello")
                    IconRightWidget:
                        icon: "clock"


        MDBottomNavigation:
            MDBottomNavigationItem:
                name: 'screen 1'
                text: 'Back'
                icon: "arrow-left"
                on_tab_release: root.manager.current = "main_screen"


            MDBottomNavigationItem:
                name: 'screen 2'
                text: 'ADD'
                icon: "calendar-plus"
                on_tab_release: root.create_new_date_picker()
```

[Screenshot - List is just on half screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vfgna.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add the content under every bottom item and that will fix it, you can also use RecycleView to optimize memory, use the code:

```
<CreateScreen>
    name: "create_screen"
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'
        #do not put the content of your screen or scrollview here,
        #because the bottom toolbar has its own screen body


        MDBottomNavigation:
            MDBottomNavigationItem:
                name: 'screen 1'
                text: 'Back'
                icon: "arrow-left"
                #on_tab_release: root.manager.current = "main_screen"
                ScrollView:
                    MDList:
                        TwoLineAvatarIconListItem:
                            id: list1
                            text: "jbsidis"
                            secondary_text: "Time"
                            IconLeftWidget:
                                icon: "pencil"
                                on_release: print("Hello")
                            IconRightWidget:
                                icon: "clock"
                        TwoLineAvatarIconListItem:
                            canvas:
                                Color:
                                    rgba: [0,1,0,.3]
                                Rectangle:
                                    pos: self.pos
                                    size: self.size
                            id: list1
                            text: "El Salvador"
                            secondary_text: "Time"
                            IconLeftWidget:
                                icon: "pencil"
                                on_release: print("Hello")
                            IconRightWidget:
                                icon: "clock"
                        TwoLineAvatarIconListItem:
                            id: list1
                            markup: True
                            text: "[i]New promotions"
                            secondary_text: "Time"
                            IconLeftWidget:
                                icon: "pencil"
                                on_release: print("Hello")
                            IconRightWidget:
                                icon: "clock"
                        TwoLineAvatarIconListItem:
                            canvas:
                                Color:
                                    rgba: [0,0,1,.3]
                                Rectangle:
                                    pos: self.pos
                                    size: self.size
                            id: list1
                            text: "jbsidis"
                            secondary_text: "Time"
                            IconLeftWidget:
                                icon: "pencil"
                                on_release: print("Hello")
                            IconRightWidget:
                                icon: "clock"
                        TwoLineAvatarIconListItem:
                            id: list1
                            text: "jbsidis"
                            secondary_text: "Time"
                            IconLeftWidget:
                                icon: "pencil"
                                on_release: print("Hello")
                            IconRightWidget:
                                icon: "clock"
                        TwoLineAvatarIconListItem:
                            id: list1
                            text: "jbsidis"
                            secondary_text: "Time"
                            IconLeftWidget:
                                icon: "pencil"
                                on_release: print("Hello")
                            IconRightWidget:
                                icon: "clock"
                        TwoLineAvatarIconListItem:
                            id: list1
                            text: "jbsidis"
                            secondary_text: "Time"
                            IconLeftWidget:
                                icon: "pencil"
                                on_release: print("Hello")
                            IconRightWidget:
                                icon: "clock"
                        TwoLineAvatarIconListItem:
                            id: list1
                            text: "jbsidis"
                            secondary_text: "Time"
                            IconLeftWidget:
                                icon: "pencil"
                                on_release: print("Hello")
                            IconRightWidget:
                                icon: "clock"
                        TwoLineAvatarIconListItem:
                            id: list1
                            text: "jbsidis"
                            secondary_text: "Time"
                            IconLeftWidget:
                                icon: "pencil"
                                on_release: print("Hello")
                            IconRightWidget:
                                icon: "clock"


            MDBottomNavigationItem:
                name: 'screen 2'
                text: 'ADD'
                icon: "calendar-plus"
                #on_tab_release: root.create_new_date_picker()
                ScrollView:
                    MDList:
                        TwoLineAvatarIconListItem:
                            id: list1
                            text: "jbsidis"
                            secondary_text: "Time"
                            IconLeftWidget:
                                icon: "star"
                                on_release: print("Hello")
                            IconRightWidget:
                                icon: "clock"
                        TwoLineAvatarIconListItem:
                            canvas:
                                Color:
                                    rgba: [0,1,0,.3]
                                Rectangle:
                                    pos: self.pos
                                    size: self.size
                            id: list1
                            text: "jbsidis"
                            secondary_text: "Time"
                            IconLeftWidget:
                                icon: "star"
                                on_release: print("Hello")
                            IconRightWidget:
                                icon: "clock"
                        TwoLineAvatarIconListItem:
                            id: list1
                            text: "jbsidis"
                            secondary_text: "Time"
                            IconLeftWidget:
                                icon: "star"
                                on_release: print("Hello")
                            IconRightWidget:
                                icon: "clock"
                        TwoLineAvatarIconListItem:
                            canvas:
                                Color:
                                    rgba: [0,0,1,.3]
                                Rectangle:
                                    pos: self.pos
                                    size: self.size
                            id: list1
                            text: "jbsidis"
                            secondary_text: "Time"
                            IconLeftWidget:
                                icon: "star"
                                on_release: print("Hello")
                            IconRightWidget:
                                icon: "clock"
                        TwoLineAvatarIconListItem:
                            id: list1
                            text: "jbsidis"
                            secondary_text: "Time"
                            IconLeftWidget:
                                icon: "pencil"
                                on_release: print("Hello")
                            IconRightWidget:
                                icon: "clock"
                        TwoLineAvatarIconListItem:
                            id: list1
                            text: "jbsidis"
                            secondary_text: "Time"
                            IconLeftWidget:
                                icon: "pencil"
                                on_release: print("Hello")
                            IconRightWidget:
                                icon: "clock"
                        TwoLineAvatarIconListItem:
                            id: list1
                            text: "jbsidis"
                            secondary_text: "Time"
                            IconLeftWidget:
                                icon: "pencil"
                                on_release: print("Hello")
                            IconRightWidget:
                                icon: "clock"
                        TwoLineAvatarIconListItem:
                            id: list1
                            text: "jbsidis"
                            secondary_text: "Time"
                            IconLeftWidget:
                                icon: "pencil"
                                on_release: print("Hello")
                            IconRightWidget:
                                icon: "clock"
                        TwoLineAvatarIconListItem:
                            id: list1
                            text: "jbsidis"
                            secondary_text: "Time"
                            IconLeftWidget:
                                icon: "pencil"
                                on_release: print("Hello")
                            IconRightWidget:
                                icon: "clock"
```

Here is the image:

[image]

Comment: Thank you, but it's not working for me as the user can change the list. So I can't have multiple lists. Is there no other way? Or should I use something else as buttom navigation?

Comment: Can I make the MDBottomNavigation so small that the MDList is on the whole screen?

Comment: Yes, for doing that there are a few ways, maybe one of the best it would be if we use "on_scroll_move" i think, to Animate the MDBottom bar to hide itself (similar to what VLC Android does), that's a very good question

Answer (score 0):

I added following to the MDBottomNaviagtion

```
MDBottomNavigation:
            height: self.minimum_height
            size_hint: 1, 0.1
```

Now it just use the space it needs.